# Why do these RSpec tests fail when the app works as expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've been following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. Actually I already finished it, but I am having some problems with some refactoring I did for the last exercise of the final chapter. All I did was changing the show view for the user model (show.html.erb) from this:

```
<section>
  <h1>
    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <%= @user.name %>
  </h1>
</section>
```

To this:

```
<section>      
   <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
</section>
```

And in the partial(_user_info.html.erb) I have this:

```
<a href="<%= user_path(current_user) %>">
   <%= gravatar_for current_user, size: 52 %> 
</a> 
<h1> <%= current_user.name %> </h1> 
<% unless current_page?(user_path(current_user)) %> 
   <span> <%= link_to "view my profile", current_user %> </span>
   <span> <%= pluralize(current_user.microposts.count, "micropost") %> </span>
<% end %>
```

Everything works fine on the browser, but for some reason rspec is failing some tests, I suspect rspec is having problems calling the current_user method which is defined in sessions_helper.rb, which by the way is included in application_helper.rb. The gravatar_for function is defined in users_helper.rb. Here is the error I get from the tests:

Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/helpers/users_helper.rb:4:in`gravatar_for'
     # ./app/views/shared/_user_info.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__user_info_html_erb___3480157814439046731_47327400'
     # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:5:in`_app_views_users_show_html_erb___1252254778347368838_47378900'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in '

I would appreciate if you could help me identify what is going on here. I could find different ways to do the same thing but I am just very curious about this. I am not very experienced in Rails which is why I followed the tutorial so forgive me if I am missing something obvious. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to show the logged in user's info on the show page or the specific user whose page you are on?

Comment: Actually, I am using the same partial for both the home page and the profile page for logged in users because that specific content if very similar (except for the content under unless). The app is hosted on heroku, here is the link: [link](https://afternoon-river-7478.herokuapp.com/), you can log in with email: example@railstutorial.org, pass: foobar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got the solution. Although I am still confused. Here is the code for the tests as they were before the refactoring mentioned in my question (as they are in the tutorial, they all were passing):

```
describe "profile page" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:m1) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Foo") }
  let!(:m2) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Bar") }

  before { visit user_path(user) }

  it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

  describe "microposts" do
    it { should have_content(m1.content) }
    it { should have_content(m2.content) }
    it { should have_content(user.microposts.count) }
  end #some other tests for show page continue, also having the same behaviour
end
```

While reading the tests to see if there was a mistake I started wondering why those tests were passing if I was not signing the user in, so I added the code to sign in the user in the before block, like this:

```
describe "profile page" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:m1) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Foo") }
  let!(:m2) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Bar") }

  before do
    valid_signin user
    visit user_path(user) 
  end

  it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

  describe "microposts" do
    it { should have_content(m1.content) }
    it { should have_content(m2.content) }
    it { should have_content(user.microposts.count) }
  end #some other tests for show page continue, also having the same behaviour
end
```

And now all tests pass. I know is seems silly and obvious to sign in the user, however that's how the tests are in [the tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts?version=3.2#code%3auser_show_microposts_test) and they were working before. [Here](https://github.com/francisco-rojas/RailsTutorial-3.2/blob/master/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb) is the updated test file if you want to check it. All changes are now committed in my github repo. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Great, all that's left to do is mark your answer as the accepted solution for everyone's reference.

Answer (score 2):

Poking around [your repo](https://github.com/francisco-rojas/RailsTutorial-3.2), this *may* be the problem: there was a minor bug reported on June 25 in the Rails Tutorial with regards to the setting of `current_user` in the `sign_in` and `sign_out` methods in the **app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb** file.  The notice doesn't seem to have been posted on the [Rails Tutorial News site](http://news.railstutorial.org/), but it was sent to subscribers and it is reflected in the [current online book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code%3asign_out_method) saying to change:

```
self.current_user = user   # in the sign_in method
self.current_user = nil    # in the sign_out method
```

So, try updating [your `sessions_helper.rb`](https://github.com/francisco-rojas/RailsTutorial-3.2/blob/master/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb), and see if that stops you from getting a `nil` user.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the update. I passed that section just before the update, I guess. However, it didn't fixed the tests (but I will keep the changes). What fixed the tests was a silly mistake from my part, I believe. Check my answer for the details. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have any users in your test database. The development database and test database are two different things. Rspec uses the test database when it's running tests.

To setup the test database you do `rake db:test:prepare`.

Then you need to populate the test database when you run your specs. One great way to do that is with the [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/) gem.

Comment: current_user is actually a method defined in sessions_helper.rb, but I don't get why rspec is not calling that method. I tried your suggestion but got the same error.

Comment: That didn't work either. Although I did prepared the test database again as you suggested, just to make sure. I don't think that's the problem, as part of the tutorial I do use Factory Girl and prepare the test data base constantly. Actually, even if I call the current_user function directly from the view (not the partial) it doesn't work either, so I guess it isn't a problem with the partial but with the helper methods, just can't figure it out yet.

Comment: Do you happen to be using Devise for authentication? If so, there's some setup that needs to be done w/ Devise before you can do integration tests.

Comment: Dty, thank you very much for taking time to help me. I am not using any gem for authentication, just a normal login using rails. If you think checking other files would be useful here is the code in my github repo: https://github.com/francisco-rojas/RailsTutorial-3.2. But it doesn't have the changes in the partial and the show view yet.

Comment: I'd start by looking at why current_user isn't being set. Looks like it happens here https://github.com/francisco-rojas/RailsTutorial-3.2/blob/master/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb Put a `debugger` statement in there then run rspec. When it stops try to see what the values are.

Comment: That's a cool feature I didn't know about. Thanks for the tip. I got all tests to pass, all I changed was the code in the tests, not in the the app itself.